# Let $\ a_0,a_1,a_2,...,a_n\in\mathbb Z/13\mathbb Z$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Disprove, $\ a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+...+a_nx^n=0\ ,\forall x\in\mathbb Z/13\mathbb Z\Longleftrightarrow a_i=0\ ,\forall i$

Ok, we can take $x=0,a_0=0$ then the rest arbitrary. but what if $x≠0$?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to disprove the result, try to cook up a counterexample.

Hint: Fermat's Little Theorem